checking if SQL Express installed in Inno Setup
I am trying to figure out that SQL Express is installed on Machin in Inno Setup. so I did this
res:= RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL', 'SQLEXPRESS', installPath); 

MsgBox('Value is "' + installPath + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);

but installPath is alwauts empty and the res is always False
where is the problem?

Your approach won't work if the installed instance (or instances!) are using a non-default instance-name.

See: https://github.com/ajtruckle/InnoDependencyInstaller It has built-in support for several versions of SQL Server Express.
